# java turn yearly compound interest to monthly

Tags: java

what i need 2 do is prompt the user for principal, interest rate, and term. the user then chooses months or years.

i have no idea on how to compute the compounded monthly interest rate using a for loop. i've looked at formulas online but whenever i try to translate it into java code i fail miserably.

i know i'd need to divide by 12, but during the loop my interest and principal amount keeps getting smaller until 0. can anyone help? ty

```
 public Calculator()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean error = false;

    while (!error){
    System.out.print("Please input the following: principal, interest rate, term >> ");
    double principal = input.nextDouble();
    double interest_rate = input.nextDouble(); 
    int term = input.nextInt();
    String MonthOrYear = input.next();

    int termInMonths = term * 12;


    char dollar_sym = 36;


    if (interest_rate <= 0 || term <= 0 || principal <= 0)
    {
     System.out.println("The term, interest rate and principal must be greater than zero");
     continue; 
    }
    if (!MonthOrYear.equals("month") && (!MonthOrYear.equals("year")&&
    (!MonthOrYear.equals("Month")&& (!MonthOrYear.equals("Year") && (!MonthOrYear.equals("years")
    && (!MonthOrYear.equals("months") && (!MonthOrYear.equals("Years") && 
    (!MonthOrYear.equals("Months")))))))))
    {
     System.out.println("Please input either month or year after term"); 
     continue; 
    }

    System.out.println("Month: " + "  Interest: " + "Principal:  "); 

    if (MonthOrYear.equals("month") || (MonthOrYear.equals("Months") || (MonthOrYear.equals("Month")
    || (MonthOrYear.equals("months")))))
    {
       for (int month = 1; month <= term; month++)
       { 
       double interest = principal * interest_rate / 100;
       principal = principal + interest; 
       System.out.printf("%4d      %c%5.2f    %c%5.2f\n", month, dollar_sym, interest, dollar_sym, principal );

      }

    }
    else if (MonthOrYear.equals("year") || (MonthOrYear.equals("Years") || (MonthOrYear.equals("Year")
    || (MonthOrYear.equals("years")))))
    {

       for (int month = 1; termInMonths >= month; month++)
       { 
       double interest = principal * interest_rate / 100;
       principal = principal + interest; 
       System.out.printf("%4d      %c%5.2f    %c%5.2f\n", month, dollar_sym, interest, dollar_sym, principal );
      }

    }

   break;
```

Comment: The concept is the same, whether you compute yearly, monthly, or daily.  You multiply the rate (for the period) times the principle and add it to the principle.  Repeat.  There are ways, using logarithms, to do the computation without looping, but that doesn't appear to be necessary for your situation.

Comment: All you need to do is let the user input the number of months, convert months to years, and use the formula A = Pe^(rt).

Comment: In the above you'd probably be better off if you used a single loop, but for monthly compounding divided the annual interest rate by 12.

Comment: so it would be interest_rate * principle = amount then amount + principal?